# value from keyboard input into enums

Tags: input, enums, keyboard

```
import java.util.*;
class Main{
public static void main(String args[]) {
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int val=sc.nextInt();

Lights light=Lights.valueOf(val);
//How to take the value of variable "val" so that if we print '0' Red is displayed. 
int set=light.setVal(val);
System.out.println(light.getVal());
}}
enum Lights {
Red(0), Yellow(1), Green(2);
int i;
Lights(int i) { this.i=i; }
int getVal() { return i; }
void setVal(int m) { i=m;}
    }
```

How to use the value of "val" while enum definition.. ?

For eg in case of command line arguments we write valueOf(args[0]) but in this case when we want to use "val" what should be done..?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [ordinal()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29)

> Returns the ordinal of this enumeration constant (its position in its enum declaration, where the initial constant is assigned an ordinal of zero). Most programmers will have no use for this method. It is designed for use by sophisticated enum-based data structures, such as EnumSet and EnumMap.

If you want the enum type then you can use :

```
Lights light = Lights.values()[ordinal];
```